# App Crash while using React-Native-Contacts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-contacts

My App is crashing while using any method of react-native-contacts.

```
  function getPhoneRecords() {
 PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_CONTACTS,
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
]).then(() => {
  Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, 'failed to fetch phone Records!');
    } else {
      setPhoneRecords(contacts);
    }
  });
});}
```

Here is the function to getAllContacts but whenever this function executes my app crashes with no error.
How can I solve this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you wrote permission inside AndroidManifest.xml? 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: I did, But after including this app build fails with an error it is not compatible with gradle 6.0 also, Google play store rejects the application if we use such permissions in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If it crash on iOS :**

Check if you have updated your Info.plist file. You must have the key «Privacy - Contacts Usage Description» with a sentence in value.

Follow the documentation : https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts#ios-2

**If it crash on Android :**

Check if you have updated your AndroidManifest.xml file. You must request permission, like iOS.

Follow the documentation : https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts#permissions

Comment: But Play Store Rejects the application if we include such permissions in the manifest file. My app got rejected by including SMS permissions.

Comment: react-native-contacts does not need SMS permissions.
SMS permission is a sensitive permission. If you need this permission, follow this steps : https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102?hl=en

Comment: Build Fails after includiing the permissions with this error, Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

Comment: It worked, after including the permissions and run these commands: cd android && gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try it 
const addContact = () => {
    PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_CONTACTS,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
    ])
    Contacts.getAll().then(contacts => {
      // console.log('hello',contacts);
      setMblContacts(contacts);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same experience running live via React Native with hot reload.

It was solved when I uninstalled and reinstalled the app.

I hope it works for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Add both this to the AndroidManifest.xml. It doesn't show in the documentation but you need to add this to access the contacts.I got the same problem with the new reat version(from 2023).

```xml
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```